# C program - core dumped

Tags: c

What is wrong with this program, please? Is there a mistake in cycles in indexing?

It gives an error:

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

The program should use the Gaussian elimination method. The input data are the following:

A.txt

```
1 2 3
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

dim.txt

```
3
```

c program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

static int N;
#define SEPARATOR "------------------------------------\n"
#define init_path "init_data.txt"
#define A_path "A.txt"

// Return the current time in seconds since the Epoch
double get_timestamp();

void get_2D_array(float **A, int N1, int N2, char *name);


void run(float **A)
{
    float c;
    float sum;
    float *x = malloc(N*sizeof(float));

// The generation of upper triangular matrix

    for(int j=0; j<N+1; j++)   // ----> j>N?
    {
        for(int i=j+1; i<N+1; i++) // ----> i>N?
        {
            c=A[i][j]/A[j][j];
            for(int k=0; k<N; k++)
            {
                A[i][k]=A[i][k]-c*A[j][k];
            }
            
        }
    }
    x[N]=A[N][N+1]/A[N][N];

// Backward substitution

    for(int i=N-1; i>0; i--)
    {
        sum=0;
        for(int j=i+1; j<N+1; j++)
        {
            sum=sum+A[i][j]*x[j];
        }
        x[i]=(A[i][N+1]-sum)/A[i][I]; // ---> (A[i][N]-sum)/A[i][I]
    }
    printf("\nThe solution is: \n");
    for(int i=1; i<N+1; i++)
    {
        printf("\nx%d=%f\t",i,x[i]); /* x1, x2, x3 are the required solutions*/
    }
}

// Funce na zadání počátečních dat - velikost matice
void get_init_data(char *name){
    FILE *in = fopen(name, "r");
    if ((in) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file %s.\n", name);
    }
    fscanf(in, "%d", &N);
    fclose(in);
}

void get_2D_array(float ** A, int N1, int N2, char *name)
{
    int i, j;
    FILE *in = fopen(name, "r");

    if ((in) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file %s.\n", name);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N2; j++)
        {
            fscanf(in, "%f", &A[i][j]);
        }
    }
    fclose(in);
}

// Program

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i, j;
  get_init_data(init_path);
  float **A = (float **)malloc(N*sizeof(float *));
  for(i = 0; i < N; i++) 
  {
      A[i] = (float *)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
  }

  printf(SEPARATOR);
  printf("Matrix size:            %dx%d\n", N, N);
  printf(SEPARATOR);

  double total_start = get_timestamp();



  // Initialize data
  get_2D_array(A, N, N, A_path);


  // Run Gaussian elimination with measured time
  double solve_start = get_timestamp();
  run(A);
  double solve_end = get_timestamp();


  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
  {
    free(A[i]);
  }
  free(A);
  return 0;
}

double get_timestamp()
{
  struct timeval tv;
  gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
  return tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec*1e-6;
}
```

It consists of a procedure run that performs the Gaussian elimination and other procedures carrying out the input data. The time is measured.

Answer (score 3):

In the `run` function, the two loops run up to and including `N`. Your allocations only cover N items, meaning indices from 0 up to and including N-1.

Comment: And `x[N]=A[N][N+1]/A[N][N];` breaks the array bounds too. Only `N` elements have been allocated.

Comment: Thank you. Could you be more specific, please? I added to the code what I edited. Is it what you meant? Are there other mistakes?

Comment: At the very last iteration of your loops, j=N and i=N. For an array where you have allocated space for N items the allowed indices are 0,1,2...,N-1. N is out of bounds. You need to either allocate more space or change the maximum index. I'm not sure but I think that in this case you want to run N iterations of the outer loop, meaning that the exit condition is j<N. Same for inner loop.